# Paid application upload facility for Indian devs in google play

Tags: android

I recently happened to see Indian developer can upload paid apps in android google play in some private sites but when I actually looked at official site the country name was not specified under the list ,

I am in dilemma that whether India is added under android apps selling countries or not ...

Comment: India is not merchant company yet.
 https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324
It's a mistake on page.

Comment: Fake news. It was mistake from Google. Visit page once again. It has been updated. India is not in the list.

Comment: Check this page*http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/no-paid-apps-in-google-play-for-indian-developers-271886*. They says it was a mistake.

Comment: what is the current status??
Can Indians now upload their free/paid app or not??

Answer (score 4):

Supported locations for merchants
Currently, developers in the below countries may register as Google Checkout merchants and sell paid applications:

Argentina*
Australia
Austria
Belgium
Brazil
Canada
Czech Republic
Denmark
Finland
France
Germany
Hong Kong
India
Ireland
Israel
Italy
Japan
Mexico
Netherlands
New Zealand
Norway
Poland
Portugal
Russia
Singapore
Spain
South Korea
Sweden
Switzerland
Taiwan
United Kingdom
United States

Answer (score 1):

It's added now. Add a merchant account and start selling your app.

QUOTE:

```
Supported locations for merchants
We are pleased to announce that today we are adding support for Google Play 
Developer merchants in India. If you are a developer based in India, you may now 
register as Google Checkout Merchant through your Google Play Developer account 
in order to sell apps on Google Play.
```